# Pycharm jupyter-notebook change coding style

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pycharm

I have been working with Pycharm Professional, however, one aspect that constantly frustrates me is the split IDE, on the left you have your code and on the right the jupyter-notebook style view, example:

[image]

I have bene looking around and saw some people having Pycharm as a jupyter-notebook style:

[image]

Is there a way I can switch to the jupyter-notebook style IDE?

P.S. I am sorry if the title and body are very poorly written, I am having a hard time explaining this properly.

Comment: Try reading [this paragraph](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/jupyter-notebook-support.html#editor)

Comment: Already saw that article, in the preview mode I am unable to edit the code, I would like to be similar to jupyter-notebook and have ability to edit/write code

Comment: If you mean having the block and the output right after, you should really just use the browser (or [Datalore](https://datalore.jetbrains.com/))

Comment: Yeah cell based output, so Pycharm Pro doesn't have this option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PyCharm Pro does not support the following style anymore.

There is an alternative that is currently under the development by JetBrain:

[DataSpell](https://www.jetbrains.com/dataspell/)

Alternatively you can use

[Datalore](https://datalore.jetbrains.com)